# Which Controller is Used in App?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

i am starting a new project based upon some Sketch design. It has following two designs: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QCU3.jpg) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEYa8.jpg) so my question is how to accomplish this effect, which UIViewController is used here, is there some code example similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both most likely using either a `UITableview` or `UICollectionView`.

The cells are customised with what looks like a clear background and shadows all over the place.

They should be fairly straight forward to do. Just very unusual in that you'll have to set a clear background on the cell and add views for the data/images etc...